# c Change digit in Integer

Tags: c

I want to create a program if given number has 9, change it 7, 
and (4 to 9). and find maximum. ex: i/p = 998, o/p = 778

ex: i/p = 499 444
    o/p = 999
how to do that.

How to use loop, array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2], b[2], max, i;
    scanf("%d %d", &a[2], &b[2]);
    for(i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==4)
            a[i]=9;
        else if(a[i]==9)
            a[i]=7;
        for(i=0; i<b; i++)
        {

        if(b[i]==4)
                b[i]=9;
            else if(b[i]==9)
                b[i]=7;
        }
    }
    if(a<b)
        max=b;
    else
        max=a;
    printf("%d", max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Input as a string, and overwrite every `'9'` with a `'7'`.

Comment: Note that writing to `&a[2]` breaks the bounds of the array.

Comment: `for(i=0; i<a; i++)` won't work because `a` is not an integer - turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: "*How to use loop, array*" this are very basic and general questions, which a best answered by reading a C primer.

Comment: @WeatherVane, can u find me for example of number changing in c

Answer (score 0):

You can read the number as a string

```
char your_string[10];
fgets(your_string,sizeof(your_string),stdin);

for(i=0;i<strlen(your_string)-1;i++){
    if(your_string[i]=='9') your_string[i] == '7';
}

int x = atoi(your_string);
```

(if you use fgets use i < strlen(your_string) - 1 because the last char is '\n' and include string.h for strlen)

Comment: i have two string, so is it right?
char a[2], b[2];

Comment: use this for the two numbers and them compare normaly